# UIButton doesn't renew it's image after setImage: is called

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

Here is the problem - I have a class, which is a subclass of UIView (a card). It creates a button on itself and it's calling changeStateIndicator: when user touches it.

Then the card has to flip after the button is pressed and the button should change it's color (actually, the image). But it's not happening at all, so the flip starts before button has changed. Here is my code:

```
//Adding a button to my view
UIButton *changeStateButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[changeStateButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageToInitWith] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[changeStateButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageToInitWith] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
changeStateButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
changeStateButton.center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2+([myWord length]*8)+17, 35);
changeStateButton.tag = 77;
[changeStateButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeStateIndicator:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addSubview:changeStateButton];

//Method which is called when the button is touched
- (void)changeStateIndicator:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StateYellow"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StateYellow"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    currentWord.done = [NSNumber numberWithInt:currentWord.done.intValue-10];
    [self prepareForTest];
}

//Method which flips the card
- (void)prepareForTest
{
    testSide = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cal_small3"]];
    [UIView transitionFromView:self toView:testSide duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight completion:nil];
}
```

My guess is that the sender doesn't change it's image until the method -changeStateIndicator comes to it's end, but I'm not pretty sure this is the actual problem. Help me please.

Comment: did u try without calling the method prepareForTest to check if the button change its color as you will expect?

Comment: also what about delaying the animation

Comment: It works fine without prepareForTest)I know that, since we are working on the same project)

Comment: Yeah, without calling prepareForTest everything works just fine. Delaying actually solved the problem. Still i think there is a better solution, but thanks a lot, really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try just deferring this call:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self prepareForTest]; });
```

If that sort of works but its still not how you want it, then use dispatch_after() or

```
[self performSelector:@selector(prepareForTest) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25f];
```

(You can use the second call with a time of "0" instead of the dispatch if you want - same thing.)

Comment: Can anybody tell mem what's the reason why we should move that ti the main thread?Or maybe the main reason is in making it async?

Comment: The issue is this: when that action message is called he button is still hilited, so you way to defer any long running task til after that event has occurred, to let the button refresh. This action message is coming in on the main thread, since thats how UIKit works. Now, you could dispatch the test to any thread IF AND ONLY IF you know that ANY IVAR OR PROPERTY that might be accessed is in fact thread safe (both setting/clearing and using) - in 99% of the time IT IS NOT THREAD SAFE. Unless you have a REALLY good reason to thread this don't. If you do you need to architect how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go one more time through the run loop for the button to redraw itself when its `drawRect:` method is called. The `setImage:` method just sets the image it will use when it does so. Instead you start an animation before this happens. This is why a really short delay fixes the problem.

Another way to fix this that might even be aesthetically more appealing is to animate the button image change. When that animation is complete start the other one.